# What is the notation used when writting the answer to a division in remainder notation?

Tags: terminology

Not a big problem nor something mind boggoling, I just wanted to know if I were to write the answer for an equation such as 10/4, in remainder notation, would it be fine to write it as  2 r 2, or would I have to write 2 remainder 2?

Comment: As an aside, $2r2$ (or however you choose to write it) is a _terrible_ notation, because by its own it's meaningless. For instance, $8\div 3$, $12\div 5$ and $16\div 7$ are completely different numbers, but somehow they are all $2r2$? The divisor ought to be included in the notation somehow.

Comment: @Arthur True so $2+\frac23$,$2+\frac25$,$2+\frac27$ would solve that?

Comment: @RayDanish I'll even accept $2\frac23,2\frac25$ and $2\frac27$, but yes, something along those lines that would probably be best.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the context.

The $2$ remainder $2$ is more readable that $2r2$.

I would write it as $10=2\times 4+2$ or $\frac {10}{4}= 2+\frac {2}{4}$ or $Q=2$ and $R=2$

Answer (score 0):

I believe the accepted notation is {quotient} R {remainder} for integer division and {quotient} + $\frac{remainder}{divisor}$ for polynomial division. So $\frac{50}{15} = 3  R 5$ and $\frac{x^2+x+1}{x} = x + 1+\frac1{x}$